# Recording from user mic w/o using Flash

Tags: flash, scripting, microphone

Is there a way to not to use flash as a platform for mic recording based script?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You could write it in C, C++, C#, Java, Fortran, Pascal, Ada, Assembly, BASIC, Visual BASIC, .............

I assume this isn't what you wanted to know, so could you be more specific?

Comment: I need something where someone can go to my website with a microphone, and speak into it and have it so I can hear it live. I only need this one way from the person logging in. Very important. For person logging in, their microphone is "hot" constantly. Logged in person should not have to click or type anything before speaking. Ok for very first time, but after that, must be live...